# Can anyone help with this font problem?

Tags: fonts

[image]

(The above screenshot is of a drop-down menu, by the way.)

So, I've been having problems for the last while where some text (not all) is scrunched up like in the screenshot above. I've tried fiddling around with the font settings, resetting font settings to default, etc., but I haven't found anything that's worked. This happens in both Chromium and Firefox and it's really getting annoying. It makes things very hard to select, not to mention it just looks hideous.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Any ideas on how to fix it?

It happens whether I'm using Unity, Gnome Shell or KDE Plasma.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while, so I'm not sure if anyone will see this but I've solved the problem.

I figured it was something to do with the font itself, so I managed to find out what font it was. It was Helvetica. I removed the font from my system and now everything works fine again. :) Guess something was messed up with displaying that font on my system, for some reason. No idea why, but I'm glad it got solved!